# how to run a python file on a linux server as a page

Tags: python

I want to begin with the fact that I know nothing about linux, and I found a script that I would like to run on my server as a page, but when I goto the .py file it downloads the file!!! how am I suppose to run it?? am I suppose to use a php file and do a command to run the file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This may be quite easy (and there's certainly no need to employ PHP here)!

Given a trivial Python script:

```
> cat cgi-bin/test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

print '''Content-Type: text/html

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello from Python</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello from Python</h2>
    </body>
</html>'''
```

You can run a simple CGI HTTP Server from the command-line using Python:

```
> python -m CGIHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Then in another terminal window:

```
> w3m -dump http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/test.py
Hello from Python
```

This is useful for testing CGI scripts on your local machine. If you want to configure a production HTTP server for serving Python content, then you're best off asking at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy task, especially if you are not good with Linux, but take a look at this:

http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#installing-your-cgi-script-on-a-unix-system

Answer (score 0):

There are two paths:

- The [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) plug-in will run a Python script.  You need to configure Apache, and install mod_wsgi.
- The CGI plug-in will run your Python, also.  You need to configure Apache.

Note the common theme.  You need to configure Apache.  This isn't a Python question.  It's an Apache question.